# CakePHP JSON Response to jQuery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cakephp

I have the following jQuery code. The purpose of the code is to send the json data in the `data` setting to the CakePHP `addSourceDocuments()` function in the `DocumentsController` controller (hence, the `'/documents/addsourcedocuments'` in the `'url'` setting).

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/documents/addsourcedocuments',
    accepts: 'application/json',
    data: {
         sourceFileName: file.name,
         sourceFileId: file.id
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
         alert(data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert("error!");
    }
});
```

The CakePHP Documents controller has the following code. I used the instructions from the CakePHP Cookbook 2.x "JSON and XML views" page (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) in an attempt to return json data from a CakePHP controller without a view.

```
class DocumentsController extends AppController {
     public $components = array('RequestHandler');
     public function index() {
          $this->layout = 'index';
     }
     public function addSourceDocuments() {
          $this->autoRender = false;
          if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
               Configure::write('debug', 0);
          }
          if (!empty($this->data)) {
               $this->log($this->data, 'debug');
               $this->set('response', 'here is the newest content');
               $this->set('_serialize', array('response'));
          }
     }
}
```

I also have the following in my routes.php file (as instructed by the "JSON and XML views" page mentioned above).

```
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

While the CakePHP controller successfully receives the data from the jQuery ajax call (the `$this->log($this->data, 'debug');` is writing the received data to the log and it is the data I expect to receive), the CakePHP controller is returning no data (the `jqXHR.responseText` value in the `error` setting of the `jQuery.ajax` call is an empty string). The only other information provided is that the `errorThrown.message` setting has a value of "Unexpected end of input" and the `textStatus` setting has a value of "parsererror."

I expect that the `success` setting of the `jQuery.ajax` call should contain 'here is the newest content' in the `data` variable because the `addSourceDocuments()` function is setting that value with the `_serialize` key word. Obviously, that isn't happening.

So, what did I do wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have disabled auto rendering, so that's the expected result, nothing is being returned.

Having that said the solution should be obivious, either do not disable auto rendering, or manually invoke [**`Controller::render()`**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3arender).

**Update** As mentioned in the comments, the `accepts` option for the AJAX call has to be an object with keys for the specific data type, something along the lines of

```
accepts: {json: 'application/json'}
```

However, actually it shouldn't even be necessary to modify this option at all, as it defaults to `application/json, text/javascript`, which should be interpreted by the request handler component properly so that it switches to the JSON view.

Comment: I have auto rendering disabled because the goal is to return json data, not a view and/or layout. If I am reading the "JSON and XML views" page correctly, returning a result without a view should be possible.

Comment: @WillR. Look at the doc: `After adding Router::parseExtensions('json'); to your routes file, CakePHP will automatically switch view classes when a request is done with the .json extension, or the Accept header is application/json.`. You can output JSON without views, but you need to echo values manually with `echo json_encode(...)` in this case.

Comment: @WillR. To be exact, it's not possible without the view, but without a view template file, that's two different things. As described in the docs, when using the `_serialize` key, the view won't use a view template, but render the data directly, however without invoking the JSON view rendering routine at all you won't get anything, so just don't disable auto rendering and watch what happens.

Comment: @Holt The `_serialize` key is _the key_, no need for outputting data manually, see [**Using data views with the serialize key**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-data-views-with-the-serialize-key)

Comment: @ndm Yes I know, but if you don't use `Router::parseExtensions('json');`, you won't use the data view so you can output json manually, even if it's not the recommended way.

Comment: @Holt But he _is_ using extension parsing, also what would be the point in doing it manually over using the RequestHandler/JSON view combination in the first place? The latter will not only do the conversion and send the proper response headers, it will also render internal errors in JSON format, so you'd lose a lot of useful magic.

Comment: @Hot and @ndm: Thanks for your responses.

I removed the line `$this->autoRender = false;` and received an error message that the view file addsourcedocuments.ctp is missing.

So, I created that file and I still receive the same ajax error (the `jqXHR.responseText` value in the `error` setting of the `jQuery.ajax` call is an empty string).

Then I added `<?php echo json_encode($response); ?>` to the addsourcedocuments.ctp file and the `data` variable in the `success` setting of the `jQuery.ajax` call contained the value "here is the newest content."

So, all that is necessary to return JSON?

Comment: @WillR. If it's looking for a view template file, then there's something else still wrong, like the accept header not being sent, or that it never reaches the `$this->set('_serialize', ...` call.

Comment: @ndm How can I tell if the accept header is being sent? I believe it is reaching the `$this->set('_serialize', ...` call because the `$this->log($this->data, 'debug');` call is working and there is only one line of code after that line before the `$this->set('_serialize', ...` call.

Comment: @WillR. Use your browsers [**network console**](https://google.com/search?q=browser+network+console), and check `$this->request->header('accept')` and `$this->RequestHandler->ext` in your controller.

Comment: @WillR. I wasn't telling him to manually output json, nor I was saying it is a good practice! Actually the way I wrote it was not the best to explain what I wanted, sorry...

Comment: @ndm and @Holt: I've determined the final issue. The `accepts` setting in the `jQuery.ajax` call needed its value to be a hash (i.e., `accepts: {json: 'application/json'}`) instead of a string, like I had. Once I remove the `$this->autoRender = false;` line, the `jQuery.ajax` call returned data. Note: I also did not need a addsourcedocuments.ctp file. Does this implementation make sense?

Comment: @WillR. I totally forgot that it isn't ment to be a string, sorry, I'll add that to my answer for future reference. And yes, that implementation makes sense, that's exactly how to do it the Cake way.